# please help!! joomla jomsocial JA menu? website social network

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

Im doing some charity work and i setup this joomla jomsocial site. I cant get the registration to work through the jomsocial component 
here is are the credentials http://www.curingcrohns.com http://www.curingcrohns.com/administrator backend login info admin admin
when i try to make a new account it gives me this  error Session expired. Please try again later
thanks

Comment: Hi, can you tell what doesnt work?

Comment: when i try to make a new account it gives me his error Session expired. Please try again later.

Answer (score 1):

There a ton of reasons that can cause this. Judging by the fact that the form is not being validated properly when you try to register, I would look for this in your template -

```
/* --- This removes any default Scripts from the Header Buffer --- */
$header = $this->getHeadData();                   // Get the current HEAD buffer
$header['scripts'] = array();                     // Clear all current 'scripts' entries
$this->setHeadData($header);                      // Update the HEAD buffer
```

If you see that in your template, then comment it out, that should fix the issue. If you don't find that, here are some of the other common causes -

1. Uninstall and reinstall the Azrul System plugin
2. Try another template
3. Make sure you have the latest Jomsocial plugins
4. Switch the session handler